# Pass Values in URL on WooCommerce Product Page

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

Right now I pass values to a product page dynamically with $_GET params in url. I'd like to switch to cleaner URLs though.

Product URL: **/event/play/?eid=1765&wt=ou**

I would like to change to: **/event/play/1765/ou**

Current attempt:

```
function rewrite_ww_product_pages() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^event/play/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?post_type=product&category_name=event&pagename=play&eid=$matches[1]&wt=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_ww_product_pages' );

function ww_custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%eid%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%wt%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'ww_custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

The URL loads, but strips the params from URL.

**/event/play/1765/ou** redirects to **/event/play/**

I tested with a [Rewrite Analyzer plugin](https://github.com/stephenh1988/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer) and pattern matches. The second match looks to be canonical url. Which if I disable the page gives a 404.

[image]

Comment: Your rewrite rule doesn't include the product. You're passing `eid`, but not whatever `event/play` is.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I've updated. The issue is now that URL is redirecting without the params `eid` & `wt`. Event is product permalink base & play is the product name.

Comment: looks like you've tried to implement this by using an actual page with a page template, and WP is redirecting to the canonical URL of that page. A page in the database is unnecessary for this, especially if you're already using rewrite rules. Load a template manually in code when the rewrite rule is in use instead and avoid the page completely

Comment: Also WooCommerce is off topic here, this is not a place to ask dev support questions for 3rd party products